# Convert a python string into variable

Tags: python, facebook

I know it is generally a bad idea but I think for my task it should be ok. I have to deal with multiple Facebook pages, each has its own access token. Depending on user's choice I call Facebook's graph to get insights for that particular page.

My code:

```
#User's input
date_since = request.form['since']
date_until = request.form['until']     
page_name = request.form['page_name']
#Call Facebook Graph
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/'+page_name+'/insights/metric/day?since='+since+'&until='+until+'&access_token='+token+'')
```

I store all the tokens in a separate file to keep them secret:

```
token_pagename1 = 'TOKEN1'
token_pagename2 = 'TOKEN2'
```

What I want to do is to pass `token_pagename1` into my `requests.get` if the user chooses "pagename1" from a preset list of names.

I construct a new string based on the user's input:

```
page_token = 'token' + '_' + page_name
```

But now I need to convert this string into a variable name `token`.
I tried to use `vars()[page_token]` instead of `token` but I get a KeyError from `requests.get`.

Could anyone suggest an elegant solution to my problem? Thanks!

Comment: So why not just use a dictionary? `tokens = {'pagename1': 'TOKEN1', # ...}`? Then all you need is `tokens[pagename]` and you are done.

Comment: Thank you! All works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your list of named tokens:

```
token_pagename1
token_pagename2
```

to a dictionary:

```
tokens = {}
tokens['pagename1']
tokens['pagename2']
```

Then it's easy to find the token you're looking for:

```
tokens[page_requested]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary

```
tokens = {
   'pagename1': 'TOKEN1'
   'pagename2': 'TOKEN2'
}
```

Now you can access the page token via

```
tokens['pagename']
```